# How to know the link clicked by the user to set the breadcrumb using views in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, breadcrumbs, drupal-taxonomy

I'll try to explain my problem giving a little context first.

I'm building a catalog of products and to categorize them I'm using a taxonomy tree with 4 sublevels. Each product can be related with one or more subcategories.

I used views to navigate the taxonomy tree to access the products related with each subcategory. To manage the breadcrumbs in here I redefined the hook_breadcrumb() function on my template.php and this is working perfectly.

The problems start here: when I get to the last level of subcategories I have the respective products and when I click one of the products it will enter the node page of that product. At this time I lose my breadcrumb trail because I entered the node. I could get the taxonomy tree of that product to build the breadcrumbs but the problem is that the product can be related with multiple subcategory terms.

So, in order to solve this problem I think that I need to know from wich path trail the visitor arrived to the product. In other words, I need to know the last taxonomy subcategory that the user visited to enter a specific product so that I can build the breadcrumbs correctly with that information.

So, can someone help me on how to know the path that the user was before entering a node?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if the user visited the product node via a direct link to the page? In that case, _"the last taxonomy subcategory that the user visited to enter a specific product"_ will not be available.

Consider to dedicate a vocabulary only for cataloging/breadcrumb, and another vocabulary for multiple term tagging.

Answer (score 0):

You can check http://drupal.org/project/cookiecrumbs a recent project which uses browsers history to show breadcrumb